# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'product'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

Getting an error obj has no attribute on the last line of the code

```
s=[10,20,30,40,50]

product=1
index=0

while index<len(s):
    product=product*s[index]
    index=index+1

print("Product is".product)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8ae5.png)

Comment: Your trying to access a property called `product` on a literal string, not concatenating it. You probably mean to use a comma: `print("Product is",product)`.

Comment: An image of an error message is always unwelcome. Please [edit] your post to include the error message as text. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3):

Use `,` instead of `.` in print function as there is no property called `product` on string object.

Answer (score 2):

Use `,` instead of `.`

Proper format: `print("Product is {}".format(product))`

Answer (score 2):

```
> "Product is".product
```

This is interpreted as the attribute `product` of the string object `"Product is "` and of course, strings have no such attribute.  Unlike in e.g. Perl or PHP, Python does not use dot for string concatenation; it always stands for an attribute lookup.

To concatenate two strings, you can use

```
"Product is " + product
```

but string addition is slow and somewhat ugly, so you usually see one of the following;

```
"Product is {0}".format(product)
f"Product is {product}"    # Python 3.6+
"Product is %s" % product  # Legacy Python 2, still works
" ".join(["Product is ", product])
```

I also added a space after "is", as you obviously want a word boundary between "is" and the product name.

The `while` loop is also unidiomatic; you want to loop directly over the list members.

```
for factor in s:
    product *= factor
```

Of course, if the list is static, just say `product *= 12000000`

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be *syntactical* rather than *logical*

### Replace

```
print("Product is".product)
```

### By

```
print("Product is",product)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the *print("Product is".product)* , here you are asking to lookup for the "**product**" attribute on string. Which is not exists on string object.

Also, best way to iterate over the list is as iterating over items. What I means is that you don't have to manage index and then fetching the item using that index.

Beautiful pythonic code will be as

```
s = [10,20,30,40,50]
product = 1

for item in s:
    product *= item
```

And for concatenate of string pythonic way is using of string formatting.

```
print("Product is {}".format(product))
```